# String parsing with regular expressions

Tags: java, regex, parsing, string

I have a following string that I would like to parse into either a List or a String[].

```
(Test)(Testing (Value))
```

End result should be `Test` and `Testing (Value)`

Comment: Is there a question you wish to ask? Have you at least attempted to figure this out on your own first? If so, what were the results?

Comment: This cannot be done using regular expressions.

Comment: To make sure I get it, you want to pull out every outermost parenthetical, while ignoring any inner ones? If so, I believe @SLaks is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly that you need `Test` and `Testing (Value)`, then here is regexp:

```
\(([^\)]+)\)\((.+)\)
```

and masked version of it ready for java string:

```
\\(([^\\)]+)\\)\\((.+)\\)
```

Comment: This cannot handle unlimited nesting.

Comment: @SLaks Well, it handles his exact question, although so does `return new String[] {"Test", "Testing (Value)"};`. It's unclear exactly how generic the solution needs to be

Comment: Who said anything about unlimited nesting? And this one would capture `Testing (V(a(l)u)e)` into second captured group, if that's what you mean (and if that's what is needed as it is not clear from the question).

Comment: Yep the solution by serg555 is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not being clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) section of php manual. It tells you about recursive patterns, which can be used to match nested things, and about the related problems. Google it for more information.

Comment: You might want to include a synopsis or quote from the article you linked to.  That way we have a clue as to why we should follow your link.

Comment: @chilltemp: It doesn't really matter in this case; the OP is working in Java, which has no support for recursive regexes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really vague, but under one reasonable interpretation, this is the solution that can take care of arbitrary nesting depth in a certain format:

```
    String text = "(T)(T(V))(1(2(3)2)1)(a*(b+(c-d))+(e/f))";
    String[] parts = text.split("(?<=\\))(?=\\()");
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(parts));
    // prints "[(T), (T(V)), (1(2(3)2)1), (a*(b+(c-d))+(e/f))]"
```

Basically you want to `split` between `)(` (using assertions). Won't work for all cases, e.g. `((.)(.))`, but like many people have said, the requirements of the question is vague, and the general balanced parenthesis problem is not solvable with Java regex.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Parse string:
 *              when '$' symbol is encountered it deletes it's previous character and the '$' symbol itself
 *              when '@' symbol is encountered it erases the text previous to it and the '@' symbol itself 
 * @author Rama Bolishetty
 * @date Feb 27, 2016
 */
package com.ram.utilities;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseString {
    private static final Pattern dollarSymborPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}[$]{1}");
    private static final Pattern atSymbolPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9$]{0,}[@]{1}");

    public static String parseString(String inputString) {
        String parsedString = inputString;
        Matcher m = atSymbolPattern.matcher(parsedString);
        String matcher = replaceMatcher(m);
        parsedString = matcher != null ? matcher : parsedString;
        m = dollarSymborPattern.matcher(parsedString);
        parsedString = replaceMatcher(m);
        parsedString = matcher != null ? matcher : parsedString;
        return parsedString;
    }

    private static String replaceMatcher(Matcher m) {
        if (m.find()) {
            return m.replaceAll("");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
        long sTime, eTime;
        System.out.println("STime:" + (sTime = System.currentTimeMillis()) + "\nParsed String:"
                + ParseString.parseString(inputString) + "ETime:" + (eTime = System.currentTimeMillis()));
        System.out.println("Total milliseconds:" + (eTime - sTime));
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.  You seem to be posting this code on any question that mentions string parsing and regexes.